# Blender fail to close if a process is forked from it!

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Hello I am writing an addon to ease the addon development with Emacs(and other editors... when it works well) and Blender. The goal isto make Blender reload  the addon on saving.

I use ipv4, TCP sockets for IPC. I had to fork a process from blender for the socket communication, because I could not close the socket any other way, the reason: I do not know a way to make a handler for closing in Blender (however it would be very handy).

With the child process I worked around it, when Blender (parent) terminates, the init process (pid = 1) will "adopt" the child, which can be detected with os.getppid(). It works now, but It has a side effect: Blender can not be closed from the GUI, but with SIGTERM. It is funny becuse blender is the most badass software when it comes to closing :) .

My questions:
1. Why is this hapenning?
2. Are there any more suitable ways for IPC or socket closing?

I use 2.76b offical build on Gentoo Linux(kernel version 3.18.12)

I am not an expert programmer so maybe I miss something important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I solved it with daemonizing the child process.

```
class serverProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, port=9012, timeout=5.0, host=socket.gethostname(), daemon=True):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, daemon=daemon)
        self.port = port
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.host = host

# many other stuff

RPCserverProcess = serverProcess(port=9010, timeout=3.0)
```